# how to convert to a tensor form a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I tried to use the conver_to_tensor function

```
k = np.array([1,5,6,9,])
print(list(k))
k = list(k)
k = tf.convert_to_tensor(k)
k
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 6, 9]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 5, 6, 9], dtype=int32)>
```

Here i got it converted to a tensor but inside that it still contains in numpy array only.
Is there way to completely convert  to a tensor?
basically i want a tensor to contain a list/array of numbers.

Comment: To print the tensor you have to use `print(tf.keras.backend.eval(k))`.

Comment: what do you mean by "contains numpy array only" ? The array and tf.Tensor share the underlying memory representation (normally). See here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics#numpy_compatibility

Comment: @yudhiesh `type(tf.keras.backend.eval(k))` still returns a numpy.ndarray

Comment: @Andrey yes, so does that mean tensor just outer structure to the numpy array,because at the innermost it is still an numpy.array.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are expecting to get:

```
k = np.array([1,5,6,9,])
print(tf.convert_to_tensor(k))  #(remove `list()` while converting to tensor)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([1 5 6 9], shape=(4,), dtype=int64)
```